# Linux NTFS partition read/write

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs

What is most reliable commercial or freeware way to enable Ubuntu read/write NTFS partition? The data is sensitive and I wouldn't like it to be corrupted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ntfs-3g` supports read/write quite well.

Comment: quite well means reliable?

Comment: I have used it only occasionally (just to copy/move files to/from ntfs partition), but I haven't used any advanced things (ACL, or changed permissions).

If you take a look at ntfs-3g-s homepage, you can see that they mention that it's stable.

Homepage address is: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

Comment: That's my interpretation. I've never had any problems with NTFS and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

[Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/) offers a commercial driver and guarantees compatibility with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

`ntfs-3g` did not work in my case,
for issues with **enabling write permissions** to the **NTFS formatted drive/partition**, the below is a simple solution that may help:

1. Determine the path to the drive once mounted, run the below and find path of the drive relative to `/dev/sd`. The mounted path may be displayed as `/media/username/drivename` - do not use this path.

   `sudo fdisk -l`
2. The below will enable the OS to write to the drive

   `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sd`

Credits to the creator of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rylq9SDhj-s), as of now the above was tested and works on Ubuntu 18.04 & 18.10.